# white padding and image from bitmap

Tags: android

I have the following xml

```
<item
    android:state_checked="true" >
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="@color/White" />
            </shape>

        </item>

        <!-- Second layer is a arrow bitmap -->
        <item>
            <bitmap android:src="@drawable/playbtn" />
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
```

What I want is the image/bitmap to be loaded from the original size and the white padding to be 10dp. 
How can I achieve that? What's happening is that the image is scaled depending if  I add the padding/size tags above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code:

**item_checked.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
       <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Second layer is a arrow bitmap -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/playbtn"
        android:top="10dp" android:bottom="10dp"
        android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" />
</layer-list>
```

**item_states.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/item_checked" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_default" />
</selector>
```